# How can I improve my Current Region selector?

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a simple macro assigned to a hotkey to select the current region and then remove the header row. The problem is that the ranges we work with are often full of blank cells which prevent the selector from capturing the entire table dependant on the activecell.

I thought about maybe simply creating a loop, offsetting the ActiveCell and trying again until it hits an illegal range, but I have a bad feeling about this approach.

```
Sub multieditSelect()
Dim tbl As Range
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell with something in it, you bastard"
    Exit Sub
End If
Call startNoUpdates
Set tbl = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, _
tbl.Columns.Count).Select
Call endNoUpdates
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make this more reliable?

Edit: Let me add further complication/detail to this problem...

We work with a database and editing records en masse requires exporting them into excel, and the copy/pasting them back into the web interface, so it is common for us to be working with numerous tables of different size, using a worksheet like a notepad to store and modify them.

I want to create a sub that will select the current region irrespective of where it lies on the worksheet, quite possibly this is the third or fourth table to have been pasted onto the same sheet.

This makes going by the last column or last row too inflexible. CurrentRegion is ideal were it not for it's occasional failure to detect the table... so I suppose I need to build my own version of CurrentRegion that will overcome it's shortcomings.

Edit2: I've come up with a lazy solution.
Since these tables will always have a header, I'll just have the activecell offset up till it hits something, and hopefully that will be the header if an empty column is the starting point.

I think this will still be unreliable should there be a pocket of cells surrounded by empty cells in the middle of the table.

```
Sub multieditSelect2()
Dim tbl As Range
On Error GoTo errmsg
startNoUpdates
Do While ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Activate
Loop
startNoUpdates
Set tbl = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, _
tbl.Columns.Count).Select
endNoUpdates
Selection.Copy
Exit Sub

errmsg:
endNoUpdates
errMsgBox = MsgBox("Couldn't find a table!", vbCritical, "Error!")
End Sub
```

Edit3: Here is an example of where my code calls down:

[image: Example Table]

I would like it to be able to capture the table even in this scenario where a cell in the test region is the activecell... but how?

Comment: If is likely to have at least 1 column with data in it all the time (i.e. an ID/Names column), then you can get last row from that, and get last column from your headers. With that, you can build your range without using `CurrentRegion`. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the above, but generally you should avoid using `.Select / Selection`.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to get, but the currentregion is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank columns. So by definition currentregion is not what you want.   Can you give an example of what have and what you want?

Comment: added some more details!

Comment: Why not add a new sheet each time you are pasting the data from your database (instead of randomly adding data everywhere and hope your selection won't fail), and paste at "A1".... then you always have a starting point. Alternatively, you should capture the size of your data at the time your pasting it in, surely it will be much easier and better to do that then, than... hope your selection won't fail ...

Comment: I just wanted to put something together that was foolproof and could be used wherever the activecell happened to be in the table. I work with a bunch of elderly technophobes who don't like complicated things like shortcut keys, so want to make it as perfect as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to my comment, see if this helps improve your logic (see comments in code for more details):

```vb
Sub multieditSelect()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'use a variable for the sheet you want to use

Dim tbl As Range
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row at column 1
lCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column at row 1

Set tbl = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, l), ws.Cells(lRow, lCol)) 'Set the range starting at row 2, column 1, until last row, last col

Call endNoUpdates(tbl) 'pass your range as a parameter if you require this specific range in your other sub

tbl.Copy Destination:=tbl.Offset(0, 20)  'copy 20 columns to the right

'Alternative
ws.Range("W1").Resize(tbl.Rows.Count, tbl.Columns.Count).Value = tbl.Value 'copy values to specific range

End Sub

Sub endNoUpdates(tbl As Range)

    'do something with this range, i.e.:
    Debug.Print tbl.address

End Sub
```